# Azure Web Job Error: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

After deploying a Web Job to my web app, the Managed Identity that I was using locally without any issues threw the following error:

> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple
> attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.

It worked locally, but failed after deployment to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

The Web App was not configured to use an identity.  After I added the Managed Identity to my Web App under **Identity / User Assigned**, the issue was fixed.

Hope this helps someone else.